# Loading Image file in res folder doesn't work after exporting jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

So I have `res` folder under `src` inside an eclipse `JavaFX` project, which contains some `jpg` image assets.

Loading image data from these asset files works when I run the application inside eclipse. But when I export the application to "executable jar file" the line where I am loading the image gives the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    at FactoryApp.start(FactoryApp.java:66) // my code
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

I have tried the following code:

**Attempt # 1:**

```
Image img = new Image("res/" + name + ".jpg");
```

**Attempt # 2:**

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("res/" + name + ".jpg").toExternalForm());
```

**Attempt # 3:**

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/" + name + ".jpg").toExternalForm());
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I could only find the above code on every SO post.

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the resources are getting bundled into the jar file?

Comment: This is my first time working with resources in javafx, could you please guide me a little on how to make sure that the resources are getting bundled properly. Thank you

Comment: Use unzip to look in the contents of the jar file. Make sure the images are where you're referencing them in the code.

Comment: For future, dont use resources' `toExternalForm` and other tricks. Use `InputStream` directly so `new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("..."));`

Comment: You can use `jar -tf` to list the contents of a jar (Assuming you compile everything to a `.jar` file). Specifying a path starting at the classpath root may work: `/res/...`

Comment: FIXED IT by changing image types from jpg to png. This is silly and I am not sure why jpg wasn't working and it works fine with png. Thank you very much guys!